# Ampere's Circuital Law Not Working

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]

$$\int{b.dl}=U_oi_{inside}$$
Now whatever direction we take for the loop, the upper side and the lower side of the square will be opposite in magnitude and for the left side and right side magnetic field is perpendicular  $cos90 = 0$ so $\int{b.dl}$ will be zero for the loop which means there is no current inside the loop according to ACL which is correct

but
[image]
Now in this loop $\int{b.dl}$ is not equal to zero which means there must be current flowing in this loop which is wrong, why is it so?

Comment: Question and the diagrams are a bit unclear. Do you mean to say that the loop is in the plane of the page (let's call it the x-y plane) and that the direction of the B-field is also in the same plane?

Comment: @SamuelWeir yes

Answer (score 1):

Ampere's law holds in the case of your 2nd diagram. Therefore, despite your disbelief, if your 2nd diagram is an accurate representation of the B-field there **must** be a current flowing in the Ampere's law loop that you drew in your 2nd diagram. Having a static B-field with the profile shown in your 2nd diagram but with no currents anywhere in the vicinity is unphysical. If you look at cases where there is a sharp change in the B-field such as the one in the solenoid figure below, there will *always* be an electrical current flowing through the Ampere's law loop (shown in orange below). In the case of the solenoid below, the current through the Ampere's law loop is provided by current flowing through the wire coil of the solenoid.

The bottom line is that one cannot draw any hypothetical B-field profile and expect it to be a realistic B-field profile without confirming that it is consistent with Ampere's law.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have misinterpreted the use of Ampere's law.

In your example the magnetic field is not being produced by the current flowing in the loop whereas the magnetic field which is part of the integral in Ampere's law is being produced by the current passing through the open surface whose edge is the loop over which the line integral is evaluated.

One test is, if the current is doubled does the magnetic field double as is required by Ampere's law?
In your example this is not the case as the magnetic field is being produced by some external source.